# SpotFire - How to get cumulative percentage

Tags: spotfire

I need to obtain Cuml % in Spotfire; how to do? Please refer the below data-set

[Data Set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4YXx.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the OVER function. I re-created your data table, then inserted three calculated columns:

```
ActualCuml = Sum([Actual]) OVER (AllPrevious([Day]))
PlannedCuml = Sum([Planned]) OVER (AllPrevious([Day]))
CumlPct = [ActualCuml] / [PlannedCuml]
```

The first two calculated columns are your rolling sums for Actual and Planned, and then the third column just divides those two new columns to get the cumulative percentage.

You could just insert a single calculated column and use the expressions from the first two as the division factors:

```
Sum([Actual]) OVER (AllPrevious([Day])) / Sum([Planned]) OVER (AllPrevious([Day]))
```